# How to clone a remote mysql database to a local development machine?

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I've been working with a few remote servers and got fed up with the delay forwarding MySQL calls through an ssh tunnel (-l 3306:localhost:3306), so I wanted to find a way to quickly and easily clone the remote (live) database my local dev machine but most online resources were from one ssh-able server, to another, not what I wanted, clone the remote database to machine I'm connecting from.

Answer (score 2):

Connect from your dev machine with a remote port forward to the local MySQL port, default 3306

```
ssh server.address.com -R 3307:localhost:3306
```

Then on the server, from there, you can log in to either the remote server's database with a default

```
mysql
```

command.  Or from there, log in to *your* local dev database,

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307
```

This then tunnels the 3307 port from the remote server to your local 3306 port from the above ssh tunnel.

Because of this, you can directly run the mysqldump command to your local mysql database.

```
mysqldump --all-databases | mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307
```

The first part dumps all databases it can into stout, but you're directly piping that to your local database with the second half of the command.

**FYI I've left out all login information to keep all commands as straightforward as they can be while also trying to explain each bit as best I can, but for real operation, I use a direct

```
ssh server.address.com -R 3307:localhost:3306 'mysqldump --all-databases -uroot | mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307 -uroot'
```

command.

For me, this is absolutely the easiest, quickest and best way to clone your live database locally for development.